# cveCvtColor causing error OpenCV: u->origdata == data

Tags: opencv, c#-4.0, emgucv

I am doing face detection using Emgu CV in C#.NET v4.0, below is the code to do code detection.

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(currentImg);
Rectangle[] facesDetected;
using (UMat ugray = new UMat())
{
    CvInvoke.CvtColor(ImageFrame, ugray, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);
    CvInvoke.EqualizeHist(ugray, ugray);
    facesDetected = EvidenceLibrary.face.DetectMultiScale(ugray, 1.2, 4, new Size(20, 20));
}
...
```

Full stack trace is:

```
29/3/2017 12:04:46.132 PM: OpenCV: u->origdata == data
:cveCvtColor(0,0)
StackTrace::
   at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.CvErrorHandler(Int32 status, IntPtr funcName, IntPtr errMsg, IntPtr fileName, Int32 line, IntPtr userData)
   at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cveCvtColor(IntPtr src, IntPtr dst, ColorConversion code, Int32 dstCn)
   at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.CvtColor(IInputArray src, IOutputArray dst, ColorConversion code, Int32 dstCn)
   at EvidenceRepository.CameraPreview.currentImage()
With inner exception as:
```

According to stacktrace causing issue at line `CvInvoke.CvtColor(ImageFrame, ugray, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);`. I am searching the cause of this from long time without a success.

Interesting is this exception is occurring only on one machine having Windows 10 64 Bit OS. On all other testing machine (same OS) working well.

I have already checked with display drivers and latest version of it.

Comment: Are you sure that you can convert `Image` to `UMat` directly? Try creating `ugray` as `Image` instead of `UMat`.

Comment: @sgarizvi if not; then how its working on other machines?

Comment: Maybe some overlooked issues, like OpenCL availability.

Comment: Ok, i will try what u suggested.